# Google spreadsheet / docs , jump to current date cell on Open

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I've searched for this topic and have found a few threads - however, none of the answers (usually in the form of scripts) in those topics have proven to be successful to me yet. I guess I'm messing up some variables.

I have a spreadsheet in Google Docs that holds a work roster. In row B1:OI1 is just over a years worth of dates, i.e., B1 = Friday May 1st 2015, B2 = Saturday May 2nd 2015, OI = Wednesday June 1st 2016.

I want the sheet to jump to the roster of either today, or to the monday of the current week, whenever the sheet is opened.

How do I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What is the specific issue?  Do you know how to get today's date, but are having trouble comparing dates in the code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suppose you have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20142875/how-to-set-background-color-for-a-row-based-on-current-date-in-google-docs-sprea?rq=1) where the OP wanted to change the background color of today's date in a sheet, your case is very similar except that - if I understood you well - today is not necessarily present in the sheet.

So what we need is to find the closest date to today ? You mention it has to be a Monday, I didn't go that far, the script below finds the closest date in column A, you will adapt it to your needs by simply adapting the index in the array. (don't forget arrays count from 0)

### code :

```
function onOpen() { // runs automatically
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  var today = new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0);
  var diffref = today;
  var diff;
  var idx;
  for(var n=0;n<data.length;n++){
    var date = new Date(data[n][0]).setHours(0,0,0,0);
    diff=today-date;
    if(diff==0){break}
    Logger.log("diffref = "+diffref+" today-date = diff = "+diff);
    if(diff < diffref && diff > 0){idx=n ; diffref=diff}
    }
  if(n==data.length){n=idx}
  n++;
  sh.getRange(n, 1).activate();
}
```

---

**Edit :**

To check the day of the week *(yes, I'm curious by nature ;-)* you can try to change the condition like this :

```
Logger.log("diffref = "+diffref+" today-date = diff = "+diff+" day = "+new Date(date).getDay());
if(diff < diffref && diff > 0 && new Date(date).getDay()==1){idx=n ; diffref=diff}
```

From my tests it seems to work as expected.

---

**EDIT 2 :**

Following your comment, it seems what you're looking for is much simpler :

```
function onOpen2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  var today = new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0);
  for(var n=0;n<data[0].length;n++){
    var date = new Date(data[0][n]).setHours(0,0,0,0);
    if(date==today){break};
  }
  n++;
  sh.getRange(1,n).activate();
}
```

---

**EDIT 3**

For some reason that I ignore **(please anyone give advise !!)** your sheet does not return date values from the date in cells but rather the native spreadsheet values which are integers corresponding to the number of days since december 30,1899...

So what I did is to subtract this offset value from the javascript `today` variable, divide it by the number of milliseconds in a day (JS counts in milliseconds) and take the integer part of the result.
A bit cumbersome I admit but I didn't find a simpler way...

What is really weird is that in any other sheet I try dates are always returned as dates...

Anyway, for the time being, here is a working code for your spreadsheet :

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  var offsetToSS = new Date('1899/12/30').setHours(0,0,0,0);
  var today = parseInt((new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0)-offsetToSS)/86400000,10)+1;
  for(var n=0;n<data[0].length;n++){
    var date = data[0][n];
    Logger.log("date = "+data[0][n]+" =? "+today);
    if(date==today){break};
  }
  n++;
  sh.getRange(1,n).activate();
}
```

**Last note :** for a better user experience, add this line of code right after `var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();`

```
sh.getRange(1,sh.getLastColumn()).activate();
```

this will select the last column before activating today's column and will place the selection on the left (near the frozen column in your sheet) which is more "natural".

Comment: Thanks very much for that quick response! The daterange is in row 1 (instead of column 1). 

I'm not so much hoping to find the closest date as all dates should be in the document - My goal is for the document to open on (jump to) the currentdate, so I suppose that would result in setting the focus to the cell of today or something. 

I'm going to edit around in the code you wrote, thanks!

Comment: Thanks again for the new edit. I'm sorry to say even with the simplification, I still can't get it to work. It must be something I'm missing.

I've made a public document with the same data. If it's not too much to ask, could you test your script there please?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vdJ_9NO4g0y1-JEIpmsdr98Hc2ywkBOxdA--gfB7vQY/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks again!

Comment: Will do as soon I'm back to a computer... Cellphone is not ideal ;-)

Comment: Glad it wasn't just me who was puzzled, and thank you so much for this solution! It works perfectly and saves my team a lot of scrolling, so thanks on their behalf as well!

Comment: my pleasure, I just hope someone will explain why this happened in your spreadsheet... thanks for accepting.

Comment: please see the note I added, it improves the sheet behavior ... ;-)

Comment: Ah, thanks! I had already changed the code to n+6 to achieve something similar. Your solution is more elegant, as the cell activation is on the proper cell, so I'll use that instead.

I'm also going to check out how to make the script run for Anonymous users as well, to which I believe I found an answer (OnOpenInstallable) in another thread - where you were the person answering as well :)

Comment: There is something here I don't get with the `date` variable. It can't compare with variable `today`. From the logs I get `Mon Jan 23 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)` for `date` and `42787`for `today`. I had to convert like this `var date = parseInt((data[0][n].setHours(0,0,0,0)-offsetToSS)/86400000,10);`

Comment: The script does not work for automatically on opening the google sheet. I have to manually got to Extension -> AppsScript and the Run the script. Is there any option to make it running in gsheets 2022.

Comment: you will have to rename the function to whatever you want and create an installable trigger. Authorization have changed since 2015 !

Answer (score 0):

```js
function onOpen() {
  // Activate cell with current date
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(),
      data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(),
      now = new Date(),
      columnWithDate = 0,
      i, delta,
      epsilonInMs = 0;
  for (i = 0; data.length > i; i++) {
    delta = now - new Date(data[i][columnWithDate]);
    if (delta < epsilonInMs) break;
  }
  sheet.getRange(i, columnWithDate + 1).activate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works when dates are in first column (column A) and you want to go to the row near the current date (you can tweak the numbers to suit):

```
function onOpen() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var d1 = new Date().getTime();
var a; 
for (a = 1; (Math.floor((d1-sheet.getRange(a,1).getValue())/86400000)) > 5; a++) 

try {    var range = sheet.getRange(a+25,2);  } 
  catch(err) {    var range = sheet.getRange(2, 2)  }
sheet.setActiveSelection(range);
}
```