# Jump to current date cell (dates are in one row) Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, date, google-sheets

I have a google sheets spreadsheet. Row 2 contains dates e.g. 25/08/2020, 26/08/2020 going across many columns. Is there a script I can run to make it jump to the cell containing the current date when the document is first opened?

I know there is OnOpen() method which you define and it runs on opening the document, however, it is getting the code that actually works that's proving difficult.

Note: I have looked at [Google spreadsheet / docs , jump to current date cell on Open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31098525/google-spreadsheet-docs-jump-to-current-date-cell-on-open) but the solutions don't work (I assume due to me having my dates all in one row).

I don't know javascript really well, I understand a little of the basics. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Sam, can you check if my solution worked for you ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you found at  [Google spreadsheet / docs , jump to current date cell on Open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31098525/google-spreadsheet-docs-jump-to-current-date-cell-on-open) does not work for you as it only checks the first column.
I modified this code a little to search for dates on a row. 
Change rowWithDates variable as needed.

```js
function onOpen() { // runs automatically
  
  var rowWithDates = 2; // change as needed
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sh.getDataRange()
  var data = range.getValues();
  var today = new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0);
  var diffref = today;
  var diff;
  var idx;
  for(var n=0;n<range.getWidth();n++){
    var date = new Date(data[rowWithDates-1][n]).setHours(0,0,0,0);
    diff=today-date;
    if(diff==0){break}
    Logger.log("diffref = "+diffref+" today-date = diff = "+diff);
    if(diff < diffref && diff > 0){idx=n ; diffref=diff}
    }
  if(n==data.length){n=idx}
  n++;
  sh.getRange(rowWithDates, n).activate();
}
```

Comment: I think it will work as long as the cell format is set to "date". The dates are just a number under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code that was provided in the answer you cited in your question, you just need to change a couple of things:

1. Make it look in a row, rather than a column (note that the data array is changing the second array dimension, rather than the first); and
2. Make it look in a **specific** row, rather than just hardcoded to the first (you could just, instead of 0, have the array use a variable "row"; instead, I just had the code pull the data for only the row with dates - this is faster for very large spreadsheets).

```
    function onOpen() {
      var row = 8;  //set this to be the row with the dates
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
      var data = sh.getDataRange();
      var datesrow = sh.getRange(row,data.getColumn(),row,data.getWidth()).getValues();
      var today = new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0);
      for(var n=0;n<datesrow[0].length;n++){
        var date = new Date(datesrow[0][n]).setHours(0,0,0,0);
        if(date==today){break};
      }
      console.log(n);
      n++;
      sh.getRange(row,n).activate();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

While the other solutions might work for now, when working with Dates is recommended to consider **display values** instead. It is also highly recommended to get rid of old for loops and var declarations.

This will be a more futureproof solution:

```
function onOpen() {
    
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sh =ss.getActiveSheet();
  
  const today = new Date(); 
  const today_year= today.getFullYear();
  const today_month = addZero(today.getMonth()+1);
  const today_day = addZero(today.getDate());
  const today_date =   today_day.toString() + "/" + today_month.toString() + "/" + today_year.toString();
  
  function addZero(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i;
  }
  return i;
}

  const dates = sh.getRange(2,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues().flat(1);
  dates.forEach((d,index)=>{ 
     if (d===today_date){
        sh.getRange(2,index+1).activate();}});
 
}
```

### References:

[getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues)