# Color rows based on date in merged cell in first column in Google Sheet script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet sort of like below, dates in the first column in a merged cell spanning a few rows. I am trying to make a script that automatically colors the rows (or the text) when the date in the first column is equal to the date the script is run. In the example screenshot, when the date is October 1st, rows 11-15 should be colored. Since the script also ran the day before, rows 6-10 are already colored at this point. This is probably possible using conditional formatting, but I also want to apply other functions to these cells (such as locking them from editing) so I need to do it in a script.

I found several similar questions, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20143611/8422322), but I was not able to adapt any of them to my spreadsheet. Maybe the merged cell is causing problems?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

- The following script will get the date value for the first cell of
  every merged range in column A of `Sheet1`.
- It will compare that date value with the date of today.
- If there is a match between the cell date and the date today, then it
  will color the rows (until column F) with orange. Otherwise, it will
  color them with white color.

---

### Solution:

```
function myFunction() {
  
  const today = (new Date()).toLocaleString("sv-SE").slice(0,10);
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  const range = sh.getRange("A1:A"+sh.getLastRow());

  const mergedRanges = range.getMergedRanges();
  
  mergedRanges.forEach(mR=> 
     {                  
     temp_vals = mR.getValues().flat();
     cell_date = (new Date(temp_vals[0]).toLocaleString("sv-SE").slice(0,10));
  
     if(today === cell_date) {
       sh.getRange(mR.getRow(),mR.getColumn(),mR.getHeight(),6).setBackground('#FF8C00');
     }   
  else{
       sh.getRange(mR.getRow(),mR.getColumn(),mR.getHeight(),6).setBackground('#ffffff');   
  }
     });
}
```

---

### References:

- [getMergedRanges()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getMergedRanges())
- [setBackground()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundcolor)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: if you don't want to make the previous days' colors white, then simply remove the else statement and leave only the if condition.

Comment: Thanks again :) I should probably ask another question, but I'll ask it here anyway. The sheet this is running on is locked, with only a given range unlocked. Can I now also lock the cells which are colored, keeping the rows for later days unlocked?

Comment: @avs thanks for your response. Unfortunately, I don't know the answer. Could you please ask a dedicated question for this scenario so other experts can also help you with that ? Thanks again and sorry for the inconvenience. If my answer solved your issue, consider accepting it and upvoting it :)

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64143180/remove-rows-from-sheet-lock-exception-based-on-date-in-merged-cell-in-first-colu

Comment: @avs I will review it in a couple of hours