# Remove rows from sheet lock exception based on date in merged cell in first column in Google Sheet script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is a follow-up to this question and the anser by Marios. I have changed the code a little to change the formatting for all dates up to and including today, instead of just today. Adding a little more context, my code now is:

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var protection = sh.protect().setDescription('Registration closed');
var unprotected = sh.getRange(6, 2, 18, 6);
protection.setUnprotectedRanges([unprotected]);

function myFunction() {
  
  const today = (new Date()).toLocaleString("sv-SE").slice(0,10);
  const range = sh.getRange("A6:A"+sh.getLastRow());
  const mergedRanges = range.getMergedRanges();
  
  mergedRanges.forEach(mR=> 
     {                  
     temp_vals = mR.getValues().flat();
     cell_date = (new Date(temp_vals[0]).toLocaleString("sv-SE").slice(0,10));
  
     if(today >= cell_date) {
       sh.getRange(mR.getRow(),mR.getColumn(),mR.getHeight(),6).setBackground('#FF8C00');
     }
     });
}
```

The code from Marios succesfully formats rows 18-23. I am running this script on a sheet that is locked with the exception of a couple of rows. I am now trying to also lock the colored cells to avoid editing, effectively removing the exception for these rows. I tried to insert

```
var unprotected = regsheet.getRange(mR.getRow(),mR.getColumn(),mR.getHeight(),7);
```

into an else condition of the if statement (and moving the protection code to after the function), but I think this variable gets overwritten in the loop so it is not one range that can be to unprotected.

My Sheet looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your current issue and goal. Can I ask you about the detail of them? And also, about `I tried to insert`, where did it to?

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation:

- The following script will protect from editing the **new range of
  colored cells** after they have been colored. It takes advantage of
  the [Protection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#setunprotectedrangesranges) class.
- The ranges that are already **locked** will **remain locked**.
- The ranges that are **not locked** and they don't need to be colored
  the day the script runs, will **remain unlocked**.

### Solution:

```
function myFunction() {
  
  const today = (new Date()).toLocaleString("sv-SE").slice(0,10);
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const range = sh.getRange("A1:A"+sh.getLastRow());
  const mergedRanges = range.getMergedRanges();
   
  mergedRanges.forEach(mR=> 
     {                  
     temp_vals = mR.getValues().flat();
     cell_date = (new Date(temp_vals[0]).toLocaleString("sv-SE").slice(0,10));
  
     if(today === cell_date) {
       var rg = sh.getRange(mR.getRow(),mR.getColumn(),mR.getHeight(),6);
       rg.setBackground('#FF8C00');
 
       const protection = rg.protect().setDescription('Registration closed');
       const me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
       protection.addEditor(me);
       protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
       if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
              protection.setDomainEdit(false);
       }       
     }});
}
```

Comment: This works but it seems the script does not really remove the protection exception from the cells to be colored but instead adds those cells as a separate locked range: https://i.imgur.com/HPD41HD.png